# Exploiting a Heap Overrun Vulnerability

Tags: c, heap-overflow

I am really trying to understand the concept of the attack made possible by the code given below.

I notice that `strcpy` is being used, which does not perform any boundary checks and therefore enables buffer overrun attacks. Also, since `malloc` and `free` are being used, I know this example code is trying to illustrate the concept of a heap overrun attack.

Ok. What do I know about the heap? It will look sth like this:
[image: the heap]

And all the commandline arguments can be used to overwrite what is following on the heap after them. What would I like to overwrite? And what would I want to overwrite this memory location with?

`malloc()` calls the `unlink()` makro, which takes an element (a chunk) from the double-linked free list,  and `free()` calls the `frontlink()` makro, which adds a chunk to the free-list.

Now, I know I want to overwrite some backward- or forward pointer. Just which one exactly ?

Let's have a look at the `frontlink()` makro:

```
BK = FD->bk;
P->bk = BK;
P->fd = FD;
FD->bk = BK->fd = P;
```

Whenever we call `free()`, we want to add P to the free-list. It will simply be put where ever there is a large enough gap in the free-list, I think. And now we have a look at the element below (BK) P and at the element above P (FD). And then we perform the actions given above, where fd is the forward pointer and bk is the backward pointer.

I don't even know if this `frontlink()` thing is important for this attack. Can anyone explain to me how the code given below may be exploited? Please give me an easy to understand answer, since I am really new to this matter. 
Thanks for your help!

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void winner(void)
{
  printf("that wasn't too bad now, was it?\n");
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  char *a, *b, *c;

  a = malloc(512);
  b = malloc(512);
  c = malloc(512);

  strcpy(a, argv[1]);
  strcpy(b, argv[2]);
  strcpy(c, argv[3]);

  free(c);
  free(b);
  free(a);

  printf("dynamite failed?\n");
  return 0;
}
```